# Multiple occurrences of match in row with different prefix and multiline

Tags: regex

I am not sure, if regex supports this. I want to extract all the mail addresses from the "TO:" line only. This is the given string:

```
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Max Mustermann <max.mustermann@foo-gruppe.de>
To: autorouter.test <vr.test@foo-gruppe.de>, Max Mustermann<max.mustermann@foo-gruppe.de>
CC: Max Mustermann <max.mustermann@foo.de>, Max Mustermann<max.mustermann@sda.de>
Subject: Subject-Foobar
Thread-Topic: Subject-Foobar
Thread-Index: AdiHB4KcplQHHfCjQW+1j4r7qtj8wg==
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2022 15:51:03 +0200
Message-ID: <b0c7343f0abd4f0584324df66139f779@foo-gruppe.de>
Accept-Language: de-DE, en-US
Content-Language: de-DE
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <b0c7343f0abd4f0584324df66139f779@foo-gruppe.de>
```

I can select all mail addresses with "<.*>", but not if I try to restrict it to the lines starting with "To:".

This would be the desired output:

1. vr.test@foo-gruppe
2. max.mustermann@foo-gruppe.de

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: I am using it in Java, but that should not matter, should it?

Comment: It does, different regex engines have different supported features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can use a finite quantifier in a positive lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=^To:.{0,1000})<[^@<>]+@[^@<>]+>
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Assert what is to the left is

  - `^` Start of string
  - `To:` Match literally
  - `.{0,1000}` Optionally repeat any character except a newline 0 - 1000 times (change it accordingly)
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `<` Match the opening <
- `[^@<>]*@[^@<>]*` Match an @ char between 1+ chars to the left and right other than < and >
- `>` Match the closing `>`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1k7ro1/1)

---

You might also capture what is in between the angle brackets, and if the @ part in not nessecary only use the negated character class:

```
(?<=^To:.{0,1000})<([^<>]*)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8TkXQL/1)

Comment: I removed the part concerning the @-Symbol, which is correct but not necessary, other than that, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarvinB You are welcome, if you want what is in between the brackets, you can use a capture group `(?<=^To:.{0,1000})<([^<>]*)>` https://regex101.com/r/8TkXQL/1

Comment: And of course, there is a `\G` based solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes :-) Something along `(?:^To:|\G(?!^))[^<>\n]*<([^<>\n]*)>` https://regex101.com/r/AybBiB/1

Answer (score 0):

For that, I believe that you to use the 'positive lookbehind', like this:

```
(?<=To:.*?)([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+)
```

Or

```
(?<=To:.*?)<(.+?)>
```

Comment: Apparently using a ".*?" in a lookbehind/ahead is not allowed.